# export Matrix with this format MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to export any size matrix like

```
A=
1 2 3 4 5 6 ....9
3 6 7 8 9 9 ....4
...
6 7 7 4 4 5 ... 2
```

To a file that will contain that matrix where each value is separated by ',':

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ....,9
3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, ....,4
...
6, 7, 7, 4, 4, 5, ... ,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html). Doing this:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
>> dlmwrite('file.csv', A);
```

writes a file with this:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```